# How to remove numbered newlines from string?

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm cleaning some text data and I've come across a problem associated with removing newline text. For this data, there are not merely `\n` strings in the text, but `\n\n` strings, as well as numbered newlines such as: `\n2` and `\n\n2`. The latter are my problem. How does one remove this using regex?

I'm working in R. Here is some sample text and what I've used, so far:

```
#string
string <- "There is a square in the apartment. \n\n4Great laughs, which I hear from the other room. 4 laughs. Several. 9 times ten.\n2"
#code attempt
gsub("[\r\\n0-9]", '', string)
```

The problem with this regex code is that it removes numbers and matches with the letter `n`.

I would like to have the following output:

```
"There is a square in the apartment. Great laughs, which I hear from the other room. 4 laughs. Several. 9 times ten."
```

I'm using [regexr](https://regexr.com/) for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the pattern like this `[\r\\n0-9]` matches either a carriage return, one of the chars `\` or `n` or a digit 0-9

You could write the pattern matching 1 or more carriage returns or newlines, followed by optional digits:

```
[\r\n]+[0-9]*
```

Example:

```
string <- "There is a square in the apartment. \n\n4Great laughs, which I hear from the other room. 4 laughs. Several. 9 times ten.\n2"
gsub("[\r\n]+[0-9]*", '', string)
```

Output

```
[1] "There is a square in the apartment. Great laughs, which I hear from the other room. 4 laughs. Several. 9 times ten."
```

See a [R demo](https://tio.run/##LY67DsIwEAR7vmLlJjwSC6E0SPSIGro4hUFHbCk@w9mBzzfPZjXFjLRSSsriecCugTo5EoJPsEj3yX6YkR3B3qzkQJw1DBtu90I2Y7TT4FKNp/MXhwMcWcFVYvg28T0CiTFotH9X40gPEjtqbJF9oIRMrA1v1GxI03muOiOG@1W3brb9UtWoqhq/h4tSXg).